# regex... how to suppr some text betwen " ' " but not anoteher... (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I have this text :

```
$txt1 = "aaa'bbb'ccc'ddd''eee'fff";
```

And I would want to keep that :

```
 "aaacccfff"
```

But when I use that :

```
$txt2 = preg_replace ( #\'.+\'# , "" , $txt1);
```

I obtain ça.

```
$txt2 == "aaafff"
```

(I lost "ccc" in the batlle)

thank of your help

Comment: In such cases it helps to test with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) first what your regex covers. (=It's "too greedy".)

Comment: `preg_replace` using [`'[^']+'`](https://regex101.com/r/27k7Ki/1)

Comment: Great !!! Thank :-D

Comment: How can I indicate thit question is solved ?

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on its checkmark.

Comment: yes... but @ctwheels do not make an answer, He make a comment of my question... and I can't note my question !

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `str_replace`

```
$txt1 = "aaa'bbb'ccc'ddd''eee'fff";

$txt = str_replace("'", "", $txt1);

echo $txt;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to replace characters between single quotes **''**. Demo https://eval.in/997294

Here,

> `'` matches the character **'** literally
>
> `[^']` Match a single character but not **'**
>
> `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times
>
> `'` matches the character **'** literally

So using the above regex you just match the patterns and finally replace those characters inside single quotes(**'**) with **''**

```
<?php
 $re = "/'[^']+'/";
 $str = "aaa'bbb'ccc'ddd''eee'fff";
 $subst = '';
 $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
 echo $result;
?>
```

**Program Output**

```
aaacccfff
```

Comment: What is `m` modifier  here for? Anyway, you just [reposted what ctwheels already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50104656/regex-how-to-suppr-some-text-betwen-but-not-anoteher-php#comment87226552_50104656).

Comment: Not needed `m` modifier. Made silly mistake. Thanks for pointing me out

Comment: reason for down vote plz

Answer (score 0):

regexes are greedy by default, this means they matches the longest possible match.
Your regex matches `'bbb'ccc'ddd''eee'` and replaces it with nothing.

in your case you have to use the lazy variant using the `?` operator to get the shortestest possible match,e.g.

```
$txt2 = preg_replace ( '/\'.+?\'/' , "" , $txt1);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/LUGY72388

for greedy/lazy of regexes see e.g. http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedy